# How to run different queries based on an input variable?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have to return different columns from a single table based on value of an incoming variable.

I have tried using case statement, which didn't work. Is there any way to implement this logic?

```
select
    case 
        when :var1='A1' then (select variable,value1,value2 from table where variable='A1')
        when :var1='A2' then (select variable,value3,value4 from table where variable='A2')
    end
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the CASE into the SELECT:

```
SELECT someVariable AS VARIABLE_NAME,
       CASE someVariable
         WHEN 'A1' THEN VALUE1
         WHEN 'A2' THEN VALUE3
         ELSE NULL
       END AS FIRST_VALUE,
       CASE someVariable
         WHEN 'A1' THEN VALUE3
         WHEN 'A2' THEN VALUE4
         ELSE NULL
       END AS SECOND_VALUE
  FROM TABLE
```