# Select different query based on a variable

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to execute a different query based on the value of a variable. I have a table with a lot of columns, and I want to select and rename a different numbers of fields based on a variable.

Something like

```
var varbl VARCHAR2

exec :varbl := 'XX'


if :varbl = 'XX'
    (select a, b, c from table1 where cond)
elsif :varbl = 'XXXX'
    (select d, e, f, g from table1 where cond)
end
```

I was trying to achieve this trough

```
decode( :varbl, 'XX',
            (QUERY 1),
            (decode( :varbl, 'XXX',
                        (QUERY 2), default)),
            default)
```

but it doesn't work, because `decode` should be used in a SELECT clause and i loose the name of the columns. furthermore, I get 'too many values' as error if I select more than a column in the inner queries.

I'm working on Oracle SQL.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61780826/how-to-run-different-queries-based-on-an-input-variable) answer doesn't work for me, because I have at least 30 fields to differentiate, in 3 different cases. I just want some solution that allows me to execute a different query.

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to do that? Code you posted suggests SQL*Plus. "IF" won't work there (but would in PL/SQL). If you could describe it a little bit better, someone might be able to assist.

Answer (score 1):

For this case to work **without plsql**, you may try execute both of the queries checking the variable's value in where-part. I dod not test this example, but the idea must be clear to you

```
select a, b, c 
  from table1 
 where :varbl = 'XX'
   and cond;

select d, e, f, g 
  from table1 
 where :varbl = 'XXXX'
   and cond;
```

So, the last query will return nothing whereas first query will get you all the lines you need for 'XX' value.